# Is it possible to open raster layer or stack in RGUI from the directory?

Tags: r, plot, rgui

Hi i want to open an image file which is in tiff format and i am creating a GUI with the help of packages RGtk2 and gwidgets, i am able to browse tiff format file but the problem is it is not displaying anywhere, for that i need a window or frame which display that layer or any raster brick, please anyone tell me how is it possible to do with RGUI.